# Foundation Web stuck on stopping

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, stsadm

I am trying to stop the Foundation Web Application service on one server, which is stuck on stopping. If I run the following stsadm on the server, will it only stop the service on the current server? I want to make sure it doesn't stop it on any other server:

```
stsadm -o provisionservice -action stop -servicetype spwebservice
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-2007-products-and-technologies/cc262031(v=office.12)

It affects only the local computer